# How to send data from S3 to redshift without duplicating and truncating table By LAMBDA?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I wish to copy data from S3 to Redshift.

However, the Copy command always duplicates the rows whenever the Lambda function triggers:

```
cur.execute('copy table from S3...... ' )
```

Can someone suggest other ways to do it without truncating existing data?

for commenters: I tried to push directly from the dataframe to redshift.. append

There is one library pandas_redshift but it needs s3 connection first which might solve appending issue)

I also tried
#if `cur.execute('truncate')`  it can keep the table empty but I don't have delete rights

`cur.execute('select distinct * from ABC.xyz')`

`cur.execute('copy......')`

results keep appending...

Can someone please provide any code or `right series of execution.`

Comment: Can you explain what aspects are getting in your way?  There are a number of approaches but which one is best will depend on your situation and solution requirements.  For example upserting only changed rows may be a better option or a worse one.  In other cases a swap-and-drop approach might be best.  It will come down to how much data is changing vs. remaining unchanged, are their primary keys on the table, are their dependent views, difficulty of the update (data size and complexity), and coherency requirements.

Comment: [Use a staging table to perform a merge (upsert) - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-upsert.html)

Comment: can you please provide some réf urls ? @john rotenstein

Comment: [Updating and inserting new data - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_updating-inserting-using-staging-tables-.html)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no straight forward option to copy the files to perform upsert which can handle duplicates.

If you don't want to truncate the table, there are two workarounds:

1. You can create a staging table where you can copy the data first and then perform merge option. That will also act as upsert statement.

   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-upsert.html
2. You can use manifest to control which files you want to copy and which needs to be avoided.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#copy-command-examples-manifest